# Use multiple indexes in the same array on server side in DataTables

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, datatables

So I'm using DataTables and I have a problem on server-side processing. I have this code:

```
$columns = array(
    array(
        'db'        => 'user_id',
        'dt'        => 0,
        'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
            return "<a href='user.php?id=" . $d . "'> USERNAME </a>";
        }
    )
);
```

Instead of USERNAME I want to select from database the column "username". How can I do that?

Comment: You have to tell use from where you want to grab your username? From `$row` ?

Comment: I'm using the DataTables script. You can look at an example here: http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html